# AngularJS http get from xml api

Tags: javascript, angularjs, xml, api

I try retrieving data from an api which is in xml format.
I've source for few examples calling json file but couldn't get it done calling an api.

Here is my code. it shows nothing on the browser and It does not show any error in the console log

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('foodListController', function($scope, $http) {
  $http.get('mydomain.com/api/FoodList/GetAllList').then(function (response) {
      $scope.myData = response.data.dtoFood;
  });
});


<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="x in myData">
    {{ x.FoodName + ', ' + x.IsActive }}
  </li>
</ul>

    <ArrayOfdtoFood>
        <dtoFood>
            <CreatedBy i:type="d3p1:string">1</CreatedBy>
        <CreatedOn>2016-02-01T17:22:31.645Z</CreatedOn>
        <IsActive>true</IsActive>
        <IsChecked i:nil="true"/>
        <IsDelete i:nil="true"/>
        <ModifiedOn>2016-02-20T08:06:31.905Z</ModifiedOn>
        <Modifiedby i:type="d3p1:string">1</Modifiedby>
        <FoodName>Example1</FoodName>

    </dtoFood>

    <dtoFood>
    <CreatedBy i:type="d3p1:string">1</CreatedBy>                            <CreatedOn>2016-02-01T17:22:31.645Z</CreatedOn>
    <IsActive>true</IsActive>
    <IsChecked i:nil="true"/>
    <IsDelete i:nil="true"/>
    <ModifiedOn>2016-02-20T08:06:31.905Z</ModifiedOn>
    <Modifiedby i:type="d3p1:string">1</Modifiedby>
    <FoodName>Example Food 2</FoodName>
    </dtoFood>
</ArrayOfdtoFood>
```

Comment: You need something like [x2js](https://github.com/abdmob/x2js).

Comment: I'm not trying to convert an xml to json but want to retrieve from the xml api.

Comment: If you want to handle it you want it to be JSON since JSON is the language objects are stored in Javascript, hence you need something like x2js

Comment: okay but it does not display in either xml or json in the browser. i think i need to fix that aspect first before knowing if i need to convert it

Comment: So what is the problem? You can fetch XML just the way you do with JSON.  But then you will to access data somehow (I would suggest DOM).

Comment: can i see a working example fetching data from an api

Comment: Here is an example: http://plnkr.co/edit/jP9xaBWpNeMXUJr2dR3M?p=preview

Comment: You're right Thanks, I've fixed it using $scope.myData = response.data;  instead of  $scope.myData = response.data.dtoFood;

Can you give me example of post to the xml api?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do that this way using [x2js](https://github.com/abdmob/x2js):

```
  var x2js = new X2JS();  
  $scope.list = x2js.xml_str2json("<data><obj><item>1</item></obj><obj><item>2</item></obj></data>");
  console.log($scope.list);
```

see the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/1146/).

This will work, of course if the service is giving a response and is valid XML.

*Are you loading data from an absolute url...?*